# line 19, in <module> u[i+1] = u[i] - c * dt / dx * (u[i] - n[i-1]) TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

```
import numpy as np                    # load numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
c=1
n=51
dx=2/(n-1)
t_final=60
dt=0.1
u=np.ones(n)
u[int(.5 / dx):int(1 / dx + 1)] = 2
print(u)
x=np.linspace(0,2,n)
print(x)
t=np.arange(0,t_final,dt)

for j in range(len(t)):
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        u[i+1] = u[i] - c * dt / dx * (u[i] - n[i-1])
    u[0]=1
    u[n-1]=1
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,u)
plt.axis([0,2,0,2])
plt.show()
```

when ever i run this code shows error called  line 19, in      u[i+1] = u[i] - c * dt / dx * (u[i] - n[i-1])  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: here n is an integer, since it seems to work in the range function and is also defined equal to 51! So n[i-1] is invalid since n is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n[i-1]
```

It's because `n` is not an array. Did you mean `u[i-1]` ?